# Cambiar contraseña a postgresql en Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

Tengo una imagen de PostgreSQL, la cual estaba corriendo sin problemas pero despues de reiniciar la PC cuando le inserto el comando `docker-compose up` para levantar el contenedor me muestra el siguiente error.

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
cximant  |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
cximant  |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
cximant  | 
cximant  |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
cximant  |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
```

Este el contenido del fichero docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'


services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
    container_name: cximant
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Como puedo cambiar la contraseña si ni siquiera se ejecuta el contenedor?
Saludos y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: mira las respuestas de acá https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420940/how-to-fix-error-error-database-is-uninitialized-and-superuser-password-is-not, parece el mismo problema, saludos

Comment: Ya resolvi el error. El problema era que estaba llamando una variable de los enviroment que la habia definido con un nombre diferente. Gracias por la ayuda.